# How to compare the entropy of two systems?

Tags: probability, information-theory, entropy

Suppose I have two systems $A$ and $B$ that produces the numbered tiles. System $A$ produces tiles 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5 with the probabilities:

```
P(1) = 0.5
P(2) = 0.2
P(3) = 0.2
P(4) = 0.07
P(5) = 0.03
```

System $B$ produces tiles 10, 11, 12, ... 100 with the probabilities:

```
P(10) = 0.08
P(11) = 0.05
P(12) = 0.09
P(13) = 0.05
P(14) = 0.05
P(15) = 0.01
P(N) = something similarly small
```

Can I directly compare the entropy of these two systems using 
$$H(X) = -\Sigma_{i=1}^n P(x_i)log_2(P(x_i))$$

Is *b-ary* entropy relevant here? Or is that something totally different?

Comment: Sorry, but what's X? And the index $i$ what its range?

Comment: @FranciscoTraversaro cleaned it up, is that clearer? It's just the definition of entropy here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)#Definition

Comment: The base of your logarithm just tells you what units you are using to measure the entropy.

Comment: The fact is that Entropy increase with the number of states, so you can not use that fromula to compare entropy.

Comment: @QthePlatypus in the case of b-ary entropy would I want to use the same $b$ between the two systems?

Comment: @FranciscoTraversaro so then what is the right way to compare entropy of two different systems? Is there a simple number I can compute across a number of different systems that will tell me roughly how random each is regardless of the number of states?

Answer (score 0):

The fact is that Entropy increase with the number of states, so you can not use that formula to compare those entropies. A simple thing you can do, but not the best is normalize both Entropies and then compare. The normalization is by dividing the formula by log N that is the maximum entropy for a system with N states.

$H_{max} = -1/N \sum_{i=1}^N log (1/N) $

$H_{max} = log (1/N) $

So the normalized entropy is:

$H_{N} = \frac{-\sum_{i=1}^N P(x_i) log (P(x_i)}{log N} $

so for system A, the maximum entropy is for the discrete uniform distribution (i.e $P(X_i) = 1/5 ~~ \forall i$)

And you can compare between the two normalized entropies.

This is a fair approach, but it depends what you are doing you can improve this with other measures.

Comment: I don't understand this. Firstly, just because the support of one distribution is larger than another does not mean that it's entropy is larger as well - for instance, $p = (1/2,1/2), q = (0.998.0.001, 0.001)$ (further, entropy is invariant to increasing states if the new states have mass $0$). Secondly, why is normalising necessary? It seems perfectly natural to ask which of two sources has larger entropy, no matter their supports. It seems you have a particular application in mind where this normalisation is useful, and it would greatly improve this answer if you explicitly state this.

Comment: you measure entropy to know the uncertainty of the system being in a given state, so if you have two systems $p = (1/2,1/2)$ and $ q= (1/3,1/3,1/3)$ the distribution is the same but the entropy is larger in the second system.  Of course in the second system you may have more uncertainty because you have one state more.

Comment: So it depends why you are using the entropy, you are right on that.

Comment: "distribution is same but entropy is more" - I disagree. The distributions are _described_ in a _similar_ way - "uniform distribution on $N$ states," but they are most certainly not the same. Further "of course, entropy is larger because you have one state more" does not hold in general - this is precisely what I was trying to say in the previous comment.

Comment: I use to work with systems that the amount of states was defined by the observer, so I use to measure how far they were for the uniform distribution using entropy, and that's why I use normalization. 
But on the other hand when Shannon presents the entropy (A Mathematical Theory of Communication - Shannon - 1948), one of its properties is: 
" If all the $p_i$ are equal, $p_i = 1/n$ , then $H$ should be a monotonic increasing function of $n$. With equally
likely events there is more choice, or uncertainty, when there are more possible events"

Comment: So you are right that my answer is not for general use.

Comment: @FranciscoTraversaro you note that this is not the best strategy, do you have a suggestion on how to better compare?

Comment: It depends what is you want to compare. As been said here, you can compare Entropies directly if you want to compare "amount of information contained". If you want to compare the uncertainty in each system, and you think that the number of states is artificial, you can use the normalization I proposed. If you want to compare between two distributions, you can use a Divergence, as the Kullback Leiber Divergence. Perhaps I can help you more if you make another post explaining why do you want to compare both systems..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course it's right to compare the entropies, as long as you use the same base (I'm not sure what you mean by $b-ary$ entropy?, I guess you meant base $2$, i.e., entropy ).

To start getting the idea, you might consider the case of a source $A$ with, say, 4 equiprobable outputs and a second source $B$ with (say) 64 equiprobable outputs. Then, you get that the entropies are respectively $H_A=2 $ bits , $H_B=6$ bits. Which makes sense, as that's the average amount of bits you need to represent an output in each case.

Comment: I was discussing entropies with someone and they were normalizing the entropy of the various states by changing the base for each system. So if the system had 10 states then they were calculating the entropy using $log_{10}$ and if the next system has 25 states then they calculate the entropy of that system using $log_{25}$. The result is that the entropy for every system is between 0 and 1, but what does an entropy of 0.9 mean in those two cases then?

Comment: And by b-ary entropy I mean https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)#b-ary_entropy

Comment: "normalizing the entropy of the various states by changing the base for each system" That would amount to compute a sort of "relative entropy" with respect to the maximum possible entropy. That could be useful in some scenarios, but then it does not make sense to compare that entropy with another with another support.